Change underline width in DropDownButton
I am using Flutter and dropdown_button2 library. I made dropdown button with the library, but its underline is getting out the border.
Those red circles are things that I want to get rid of.
Here is my source code about the button:
Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 30,
          ),
          child: DropdownButton2<String>(
            isExpanded: true,
            hint: Text(
              AppLocalizations.of(context)!.dropDownButtonHintText,
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 16,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            items: languages
                .map(
                  (
                    String language,
                  ) =>
                      DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: language,
                    child: Text(
                      language,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 14,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
            value: selectedValue,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(
                () {
                  selectedValue = value;
                },
              );
            },
            dropdownSearchData: DropdownSearchData(
              searchController: _searchController,
              searchInnerWidgetHeight: 50,
              searchInnerWidget: Container(
                height: 50,
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 8,
                  bottom: 4,
                  right: 8,
                  left: 8,
                ),
                child: TextFormField(
                  expands: true,
                  maxLines: null,
                  controller: _searchController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    isDense: true,
                    contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10,
                      vertical: 8,
                    ),
                    hintText: AppLocalizations.of(
                      context,
                    )!
                        .dropDownSearchHintText,
                    hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),

                  ),
                ),
              ),
              searchMatchFn: (
                language,
                searchValue,
              ) {
                return language.value.toString().contains(
                      searchValue,
                    );
              },
            ),
            buttonStyleData: ButtonStyleData(
              height: 50,
              width: double.infinity,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                border: Border.all(
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            dropdownStyleData: DropdownStyleData(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              scrollbarTheme: ScrollbarThemeData(
                radius: const Radius.circular(40),
                thickness: MaterialStateProperty.all(6),
                thumbVisibility: MaterialStateProperty.all(true),
              ),
            ),
            menuItemStyleData: const MenuItemStyleData(
              height: 30,
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 14, right: 14),
            ),
            onMenuStateChange: (
              isOpen,
            ) {
              if (!isOpen) {
                _searchController.clear();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),

How can I make that underline does not get out to the border? (Everything works successfully else the underline)

Just wrap your DropdownButton2() with DropdownHideUnderline()
  DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton2(
              
              iconStyleData:
                  const IconStyleData(icon: Icon(EvaIcons.arrowDown)),
              dropdownStyleData: const DropdownStyleData(isOverButton: false),
              buttonStyleData: ButtonStyleData(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      border: Border.all(width: 1, color: const Color(0xff3C53CA)),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10))),
              items: items,
              value: value,
              onChanged: onChanged,
            ),
          )

